# Understanding a probability statistical question

Tags: probability, bayesian

According to the CDC, men who smoke are about 20 times more likely to develop lung cancer than non-smokers. Approximately 1/6 of the male population smokes and approximately 1/4 of the smokers get lung cancer. Overall, males have 1/14 chance of getting lung cancer.

1. What is the probability that a random man who has lung cancer smokes?
2. What is the probability that a random man who does not have lung cancer smokes?

So, I am new to probability and statistics and do not understand this question. Can someone help useful links to understand the concept to solve this question

Comment: What have you attempted? It would help show what you are struggling with as this seems to be a pretty straightforward conditional probability question.

Answer (score 1):

I filled in your data in a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table). I derived the 5/6 non-smokers and 13/14 no lung-cancer based on the fact that the totals need to sum up to 1. The 1/24 stems from 1/6 * 1/4.

I leave it up to you to fill in the three gaps and derive the probabilities

```
               | lung cancer     no lung cancer    total
------------------------------------------------------------
  smokers      |    1/24           ....             1/6
 non-smokers   |    ....           ....             5/6 
  total        |    1/14           13/14             1
```

Comment: actually, I only used the data 1/6, 1/4, and 1/14 (which should be sufficient to complete the gaps in the data). When I *also* use the '20 times more likely' then I get an inconsistency and that makes it unclear how this problem should be resolved.

$$\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{4} +\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{4}  \times \frac{1}{20} \neq \frac{1}{14} $$